# Is there a bug or a catch with the achievement for landing a combo after time is up in fruit ninja?

Tags: achievements, fruit-ninja

So I've had this achievement sitting in my list since forever it seems like. It wants me to land a combo after time is up in zen mode. It's pretty simple, really. I've landed multiple combos after the timer hit 0 and the bell sound rang. Yet here sits this achievement, still saying it's not complete. Is there a known issue with this achievement, or is there a catch that I haven't been meeting? What else could it possibly want me to do?

Comment: Can you skip it?

Comment: I can skip it, but I'm afraid I won't get the full prize if I do. Supposedly you're supposed to get a blade out of the deal and I don't know if I'll get it if I skip it.